# Best wi-fi dongle for routing

Tags: raspbian, wifi, dhcp

I want to make a TOR router from my B+.
If you have a experience in it, what is the best usb dongle for it?
I have a lot of problem with my old RTL8191SU, so I need a replacement.

Comment: I think chipset is very important. I use RTL8188CUS based wifi dongle. Good enough for my applications.

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Comment: Welcome -- but shopping questions are [explicitly off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (I believe so that we don't open things up to spam advertising).  However, a question such as, "How can I determine whether a specific wifi adapter will work or not?" would be okay.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Pi Hut's USB Wi-Fi Adapter, I have used it myself and it works fine with the B+. No set up is required it is literally plug and play. Here is a link to it:

http://thepihut.com/products/usb-wifi-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi

I believe you can also get versions which support Bluetooth as well.

What is also important is you supply the Pi with adequate power, as USB Wi-Fi adapters can be power hungry.